Is there any way to specify a folder where all the related jars are present in their own folder structure in Taurus yaml file?
Is there any way to specify a folder where all the related jars are present in their own folder structure in Taurus yaml file?
I am trying to run existing Selenium Java custom framework with Maven in Taurus
Basically I dont want to specify each jar by jar name and want to specify a folder from where it will automatically search for relevant jar

You could try using a classpath wildcard; see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html#A1100762
